# What can primes (except 2,3, or 5) be congruent to (mod 30)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I know that $30$ must divide $p-x$ which implies 30n+x=p.

My thought was to  find all integer solutions of this equation. I have that $0,p$ is always a solution so my next thought is to solve this as a linear diophantine equation. I have that $n=1+pt$ and $x=p-30t$ $\forall t\in \mathbb{Z}$. I then thought all solutions are of the form $p-30t$.

When I plug them into the equation for some choices of $t$, everything works out. Is this a proper solution and is there a better way to tackle this problem?

Comment: By  [Dirichlet's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) if $\gcd (a, 30)=1$ there are infinitely many primes $p\equiv a \pmod {30}$.

Comment: primes (except $2, 3,$ or $5$) _can't_ be congruent to multiples of $2, 3, $ or $5\bmod 30$

Comment: Should say:  Dirichlet's theorem is difficult, but you don't need it since you aren't asking about infinitely many primes.  All you need is to give an example of a prime for each of the residues $a$ prime to $30$.  There are so many small primes that this should not be difficult.  Indeed, there are exactly $8$ such $a$ and (by coincidence) the first $8$ primes greater than $5$ get the job done .

Comment: each of the least residues modulo $30$ that is invertible is prime, except one

Comment: @lulu: I wouldn't say it's coincidence; any composite number less than $7^2=49$ must have $2$, $3, $ or $5$ as a factor

Comment: @J.W.Tanner  Ah, good point.

Answer (score 4):

You are almost there! You already know $30n+x=p$. Hence, if $\gcd(x,30)\neq 1$, you can factor out $\gcd(x,30)(\frac{30n+x}{\gcd(x,30)})=p$, contradicting $p$ prime.

So you only have the numbers $1,7,11,13,17,19,23,29$. Examples of such primes that are $\mod 30$ are $31,37,41,43,47,79,83,89$ respectively, and we are done.

Comment: e.g., $31\equiv1\bmod30$

Comment: Thank you for the correction!

Comment: Why am I allowed to stop at 29 for numbers coprime with 30?

Comment: Also how do I know that the numbers coprime with 30 are indeed all the solutions I am looking for? I understand that x must be coprime with 30 but how do I know they are solutions?

Comment: 1. If you go above 29, you will come back to $0 \mod 30$ and you will just be repeating your search space. 
2. You don't (at least in my solution). What I've done is give possible solutions, and give examples where they hold, which proved that they are indeed solutions to the equation.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is prior art that I'm unaware of, but I realized those 8 scenarios under 30

> **1, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29**

for all primes can be collapsed down to a single unified formula that isn't too complicated :

---

### **`(( n % 30 - 15 ) ^ 4 ) % 30 == 16`**

---

- The pros is that one can either skip either a 8-scenario `case statement`, a regular expression, or a table lookup.
- The cons is that one extra high-cost division/modulo must be
  performed.